# MSI Z87 - G43 Motherboard booting into EFI-Shell, why and what does it mean?

Tags: boot, motherboard, uefi, bootloader, bootable-media

My PC with a Z87 - G43 Motherboard is constantly booting into the EFI-Shell instead of booting from my USB Stick.

Before, everything went fine and it was booting my windows OS from an SSD. Seems the SSD got broken and I replaced it. Now, I want to boot the Acronis Backup Recovery System from the USB Stick.

Booting Sequence is set to USB first. However it always boots into that EFI-Shell.

What is it, and how do I make the Sys boot from the USB-Stick?

Comment: Try to [Turn off Fast Startup](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: There is no OS on the fresh SSD atm. I try to boot the rescue sys from the USB-Stick. Fast Startup is a Windows feature, isn't it?

Comment: Some computers will not use Fast Boot if you shut them down cleanly, unplug, wait ten seconds, replug, and start normally.  You may be able to use a key press to go into BIOS then and disable Fast Boot until further notice.

Comment: By "Fast Boot" , meaning skip the BIOS screen and go straight to the OS.  I haven't used your particular model of computer / motherboard , so don't know the precise terminology.  Windows has some similarly-named software features, as you pointed out.

Comment: " However it always boots into that EFI-Shell." - This is an indication that the drive isn't EFI compatible.  What version of Acronis?

Answer (score 1):

In the BIOS I've gone into

> Advanced -> Windows Features -> Disable Windows Features esp. Secure Boot

That solved it. After disabling Secure Boot it booted *Acronis Rescue Media*.